# stani python editor documentation

Tags: python

Has anybody got any idea where one can get documentation for stani python editor? The doc folder in the package is empty and I have searched the internet with no luck..

Comment: You are still stuck with Stani! ;-)

Comment: have u got any other suggestions for a good python idle+

Comment: pydev  http://pydev.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a docbook-to-man command on the [spe.sgml](http://svn.berlios.de/wsvn/python/spe/trunk/spe.sgml) file.  Once you do that you can use the man command.

If you dont want to use man, you can just look at the file, or try  epcEdit.  I looked at the documentation inside the file.. and there isn't much there.

So good luck ;)